# Crystal CASE expression with SQL example using CRYSTAL syntax

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, case

How would a properly formed `CASE` statement with CRYSTAL syntax.
I am creating a international Flag field on the report to show if the order number is a international order or domestic order and the report needs to show the Order type "International" or "Domestic" in the field based on the code snippet below.

Here is a SQL example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
Select
  CASE
     WHEN order.no like '6%' then 'International'
     Else "Domestic"
  END
from Orders
```

As of now I have tried

```
select {Command.order_no}
case is like '6%' : "International"
default : "Other"
```

But I receive a error

> "One of the comparison operators <,<=,> or >= is expected here.`

Comment: case expression, not case statement...

Comment: Thanks for the advise Jarlh, I have edited the question.

Comment: can you use an IF statement instead?

Comment: I can use any method in the report, I just need the report field to recognize if the order_no starts with a 6 then its international, otherwise its domestic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two choices, use the IF syntax instead.  Crystal has a nice built-in help file for syntax questions.  Also, make sure when you copy from an example, you're using the same syntax setting (Crystal or BASIC) as the example.  In this case, it's in Crystal syntax, so if you have the syntax set to BASIC, it won't compile.

Try an IF statement like this:

```
   if left({Command.order_no},1) = '6' then
      "International"
   else
      "Other"
```

Comment: I have and actually found that exact example. However when I implement it, I recieve the error shown above

"One of the comparison operators <,<=,> or >= is expected here.`

Comment: which version of Crystal are you using?  Also, there are two syntax choices, Crystal and BASIC.  Are you using Crystal syntax?

Comment: I am using Crystal Reprots XI and Crystal Syntax

Comment: Your latest revision of 

if left({Command.order_no},1) = '6' then
      "International"
   else
      "Other"

worked. Thank you Beth I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Agree, I think crystal reports was not liking the CASE "is like". Pulling the first character was the smart way to approach it, thanks again.